# Is there something wrong with my interchanging of sums and integrals?

Tags: calculus

> Is there something wrong with my interchanging of sums and integrals?

Consider $$\sum_{n\leq x}a_n(x-n)=\int_1^xA(t)dt,$$
where $A(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}a_n$.

If I choose $a_n=2n$, then $A(x)=x(x+1)$ assuming x is a positive integer and 
$$\sum_{n\leq x}a_n(x-n)=xA(x)-2\sum_{n\leq x}n^2=\frac{1}{3}x^3-\frac{1}{3}x$$ and 
$$\int_1^xA(t)dt=\int_1^x(t+1)tdt=x^3/3+x^2/2-5/6.$$

I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: How do you define $\sum_{n=1}^x$ when $x$ is not a natural number?

Comment: @copper.hat the limit of my summation is wrong. I just fixed it .

Comment: I was referring to the definition of $A(x)$.

Comment: @copper.hat sorry check it again.

Comment: I get $A(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor (1+\lfloor x \rfloor)$. How did you get $A(x) = x(x+1)$?

Comment: @copper.hat Since the equation must hold for all $x$ real, I am just assuming $x$ is an integer.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. How can $x$ be an integer when you integrate $A$?

Comment: @copper.hat yes you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the integral. When you use partial summation, you work with integers. So, in your case$$\int_{1}^{x}A\left(t\right)dt\neq\int_{1}^{x}\left(t+1\right)tdt$$
 but, since you're working now in an continuous context,$$\int_{1}^{x}A\left(t\right)dt=\int_{1}^{x}\left(\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor +1\right)\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor dt$$
 where $\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor$ 
  is the integer part of $t$ (or floor function). As copper.hat suggested, working with $x$
  real makes problem because you are obligated to work with the floor function even out of the integral (note that in the integral case is inevitable).

Comment: Do I need to worry this every time I do the interchanging?

Comment: @DDaren Yes. Working with $A(t)$ obliges to work with integer and so the floor function. But note that $$\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor =t-\left\{ t\right\}$$ where $\left\{ t\right\}$ is the fractional part of $t$ and is bounded by $1$. By this maybe you can derive some estimation.

Answer (score 0):

In the expansion of the sum, the second term should also depend on $A(\cdot)$ and yours does not.

$$
\sum_{n=1}^x a_n (x-n)
   = x \sum_{n=1}^x a_n - \sum_{n=1}^x n a_n
   = x A(x) - \sum_{n=1}^x n a_n,
$$
but the last sum **is not** $2\sum_{n=1}^x n^2$....

**UPDATE** for the new formulation.

The sum is still wrong. For $a_n = 2n$ and $A(x) = x(x+1)$ you should get
$$
\begin{split}
\sum_{n=1}^x a_n (x-n)
   &= x \sum_{n=1}^x a_n - \sum_{n=1}^x n a_n \\
   &= x A(x) - \sum_{n=1}^x n a_n\\
   &= x^2 (x+1) - 2\sum_{n=1}^x n^2 \\
   &= x^2 (x+1) - \frac{x(x+1)(2x+1)}{3} \\
   &= x(x+1) \frac{x-1}{3}
\end{split}
$$

Comment: What should that be?

Comment: @DDaren see no easy way to simplify this, will definitely depend on $A(\cdot)$. Note that it is $$a_1 + 2 a_2 + \ldots x A(x) = A(x) + A(x)-a_1 + A(x)-a_1-a_2 \ldots$$ perhaps this will take you somewhere... not sure how to evaluate this exactly...

Comment: If you put $a_n=2n$ into the LHS of your equation, is it the same as my previous result?

Comment: @DDaren yes, it is

Comment: @DDaren please see the update - sum is still incorrect

Comment: expand your bracket, it should be the same as mine.